# How to do a left outer join in a eager_load in Rails?

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails

The following query

`Install.eager_load(customer: :invoices).includes(calendar_appointment: :technician).where("state = 'scheduled' AND start_time < ?", Date.tomorrow)`

Is REALLY slow, I would love to only return the Installs that do not have associated invoices, as that would make it run faster. How would I go about doing that? Also any ideas on improving the speed of this query would be helpful, the appropriate tables are indexed.

Comment: You can use `joins` and just write in the join condition, `joins('inner join customer on ...... whatever')`

Comment: 'I would love to only return the Installs that do not have associated invoices' so why are you eager_loading customer with invoices?

Comment: Installs are associated through customers with invoices

Comment: Can you share schema/associations of all the models you have shared?

Comment: Install  belongs_to :subscription  has_one :customer, through: :subscription

Comment: Customer has_many :invoices,

Answer (score 0):

Not sure how exactly the association is defined but here's my stab at it:

```
Install
.joins("inner join invoices on installs.id = invoices.install_id")
.includes(calendar_appointment: :technician)
.where("state = 'scheduled' AND start_time < ? AND invoices.install_id IS NULL", Date.tomorrow)
```